# Помощь с реализацией перегрузки метода

Tags: c#

До сегодня не доводилось часто сталкиваться с перегрузкой, прошу помощи с этим.

Имеется метод:

```
public char GetFigureAt(int x, int y)
    {
        Square square = new Square(x ,y);
        Figure f = board.GetFigureAt(square);
        return f == Figure.none ? '.' : (char)f;
    }
```

Для двух координат это работает без проблем, но когда мне требуется ввести только одно значение то появляется ошибка что нужно 2 параметра указать а не 1.

```
string figure = chess.GetFigureAt(from).ToString();
```

Собственно вопрос, как перегрузить правильно этот метод что бы работало с 1 значением ?

Comment: Один из способов это создать такой же метод и указать ему в параметрах на вход только одну координату. Также можно использовать необязательные  параметры, но тогда одна из координат будет иметь всегда значение по-умолчанию (если вы её не переопределите)

Comment: пробовали написать метод, который принимает одно значение нужного вам типа?

Comment: @alladuh можно по подробнее про не обязательные параметры ?

Comment: [Именованные и необязательные аргументы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример перегрузки метода `GetFigureAt` из вопроса:

```
public char GetFigureAt(Point point)
{
   return GetFigureAt(point.X, point.Y)
}

public char GetFigureAt(int x, int y)
{
   var square = new Square(x, y);
   var figure = board.GetFigureAt(square);

   return figure == Figure.none ? '.' : (char)figure;
}
```